# URL SCHEMES FOR ANDROID AND IOS APPS

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, plugins, capacitor

I need some help.
I'm creating an app in IONIC 6 with CAPACITOR and I want to be able to open other apps through my app, for example google maps. I'm using the AppLauncher plugin from Capacitor, but it seems that I need to know the url schemes of the app's to be able to check if the device has the app installed or not.
Where can I find the url schemes of the apps for android and ios?
I looked on the net but couldn't find it, does anyone know where I can find it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is an url scheme of an app? Never heard of that.

Comment: You should know package name.

Comment: From what I understand, it's an app identity on the device.
Look at the example that the capacitor plugin uses @blackapps

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app-launcher


Pugling checks if the device has the app installed and if it can open, if so it opens

Comment: There is no central registry of app url schemes for iOS. There are some lists that people create and make available and some app vendors document their url schemes.  [Google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme) is one such. Finding it was as simple as typing "Google maps url scheme" into Google. Note that your app needs to explicitly declare the url schemes (or package identifiers on Android) that it wants to check for.

Comment: So guys, I didn't know but there is a puglin created by Ionic with the name of Launch Navigation, where the purpose of this puglin is to launch all the navigation methods existing on the device, this puglin completely solves my entire process.
Thanks for your attention and help